# could someone please explain this simple python code?

Tags: python, encryption

I am a few weeks into GCSE Computing, and I am in year 9. Today we went through a program that was a simple encryption program. I didn't really understand it that much. Could an experienced python programmer please explain this piece of code, **simply**?

BTW - I have put a comment by the pieces of code I understand.

```
message = str(input("Enter message you want to encrypt: ")) #understand
ciphered_msg = str() #understand
i = int() #understand
j = int() #understand
n = int(3)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, len(message), n):
        ciphered_msg = ciphered_msg + message[j]

print(ciphered_msg) #understand
```

Please help me with this, as I would really like some more python knowledge and to get an A* in my exam.

I know how a for loop works, but I just don't understand how this one works.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, one thing is that `n = int(3)` is no different than `n = 3`.

Comment: And another is that `numbers` doesn't seem to be defined. Have you posted all the code?

Comment: Where do your `numbers` come from?

Comment: Have you tried running this code to see what it does?

Comment: `n=int(3)`maybe not the message, but the code was to be encrypted - in a Rube-Goldberg style (: is this really good programming practice? can you confirm that you understand the for loops (not denoted by comments)?

Comment: This code is not great. However, if you don't understand code, the thing to do is to look up the parts, and try them out yourself to see what they do. Asking others to explain, or attending lectures, is unlikely to be very helpful.

Comment: This is a great time to learn to use a debugger such as idle, or python eric. Use the debugger to step through the code line by line and see what it does.

Comment: By the way, this is lousy python code. the `i = int()` and `j = int()` just show that the author doesn't know python. They are completely replaced in the for loops and shouldn't be there at all. Looks like a C programmer that just doesn't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally put numbers instead of message[j]. This is not my code, it is my teachers.

Comment: Then it is concatenating every third digit in `message`, three times, starting with the 0th one, then the 1st, then 2nd, or 1st 2nd 3rd. However you read it. Placing print statements for each variable before and after each variable will help you understand more.

Comment: But not before they are initialized of course, which is what your teacher must be doing for some reason. But not necessary in Python.

Comment: @user2816683 then unfortunately your teacher does not appear to know Python very well. Sorry about that. (Since you're in year 9, you're hopefully past the stage of thinking of all adults as infallible...)

Comment: I wished I learned Python in my GCSE Computing class in year 10 - we had to use BBC BASIC - I flinch when I hear that language's name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are un-Pythonic and you should not do this:

```
ciphered_msg = str()
i = int()
j = int()
n = int(3)
```

Instead do this, it's completely equivalent code but simpler and clearer:

```
ciphered_msg = ""
i = 0 # unnecessary, the i variable gets reassigned in the loop, delete this line
j = 0 # unnecessary, the j variable gets reassigned in the loop, delete this line
n = 3
```

The loop is doing the following: starting in `0`, then `1` and finally `2`, it takes every third index in the message's length and accesses the corresponding position in the `message` array, appending the character at that position and accumulating the result in the `ciphered_msg` variable. For instance, if `message` is of length `5`, the indexes in `message` will be accessed in this order:

```
0 3 1 4 2
```

So basically we're scrambling the characters in the input `message` - for example, if the input is `abcde` the output will be `adbec`. This is a very weak cipher, it's only transposing the characters:

```
# input
0 1 2 3 4 # original indexes
a b c d e # `message` variable

# output
0 3 1 4 2 # scrambled indexes
a d b e c # `ciphered_msg` variable
```

Comment: Sorry, but I accidentally put "numbers" instead of messages

Comment: @user2816683 now it's clear whats happening, see my updated answer